# seleniumIDE xpath selector

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I am learning about seleniumIDE in firefox.

The case that I am trying to do is opening "www.google.de" , and click the "google suche" button. I used x-path add-on in Firefox for fetching the x-path selector, and getting this value for the respective button.

`id('tsf')/x:div[2]/x:div[3]/x:center/x:input[1]`. 
Just for the sake of learning, I am forcing to use the X-path selector above.

I run the seleniumIDE, and I want to see whether the generated xpath can be parsed by the seleniumIDE. Hence I used the command click, and put the following target on the base URL of google.de

```
xpath=//div[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]
```

The log that I got is

```
[info] Executing: |click | xpath=//div[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1] | id('tsf')/x:div[2]/x:div[3]/x:center/x:input[1] |
[error] Element xpath=//div[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1] not found
```

If I insert xpath=//div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1], the test in seleniumIDE is passing. I thought the div[@id='tsf'] should be the part of the whole unique xpath selector, however obviously I am not understanding this correctly.

How to fix the above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'tsf' is the id for form, not div.

```
xpath=//form[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]
```

or to be more exact:

```
xpath=//form[@id='tsf']/div[@class='tsf-p']/div[@class='jsb']/center/input[1]
```

Check out [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) for xpath help when using FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use one of attributes of target `input` element:

```
xpath=//input[@value="Google-Suche"]
```